# Modify recorded code to convert Text to Column

Tags: excel

I have a column BA. I want to do Text to Column to column BC.

I recorded a macro. When I execute it in a workbook I get an error.

Here is my recorded macro.

```
Sub Macro8()
'
' Macro8 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+H
'
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter _
:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, _
Other:=True, OtherChar:=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array _
(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array( _
10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), _
Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array( _
23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(27, 1), Array(28, 1), Array(29, 1), _
Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1), Array(32, 1), Array(33, 1), Array(34, 1), Array(35, 1), Array( _
36, 1), Array(37, 1), Array(38, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Shouldn't Range be BA?

I don't see BC - is that the 0, 2 offset?

Comment: A) Record your macro in the personal macro workbook instead of "this workbook"

Comment: B) The safest way to share macros is to go to visual basic (alt+f11) and copy and paste the code out into a text file or directly into an email.

Comment: D) It's possible to create macros without knowing any VB by only using recording, but you won't get very far.

Comment: thank you for your response! 

Personal macro - got it!! Can i use the code above and change Range from A1 to BA1?  and how come i don't see BC - which is the column i want to push the text to. 

as for not getting very far without knowing VB - i've noticed!! :-)

Comment: This site is for help with your code. If you don't know how to code at all, you may want to start with learning some simple VBA, then try something out and come back.

Comment: What is the column called BA  and why do you talk about it?  You have data in column BC and want to text-to-columns that data, delimited by commas.  You are going to put data in columns BC through CN.  Not sure how you got the offset in your code.  If I deduced correctly you need to change to this: Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("BC1")

Comment: the data will always be in column BA - that's why i keep mentioning it. because when using the Text to Columns function - you have to select the column - then click the button - just wondering why one wouldn't specify the start and destination columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: changed the destination offset to two columns over (from 1)

If you just need your code to operate on the selected cells then this should work:

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Selection.Offset(0, 2), _
           DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
           ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Comma:=True, Other:=True, _
           OtherChar:=":"
```

Unless you have specific datatypes etc you want to apply to the resulting columns, you can typically omit the `FieldInfo` argument

Comment: hey Tim - thank you for the response - am i to assume that code you put in there understands i'm converting column BA? and that i would like the columns to start in column BC? is it clear i have no idea what i'm talking about - i'm merely trying to explain what i am wanting to do. BA is the second to the last column in my export - i tried adding blank cells to the right of it, between BA and BB but some of the fields had much more data than the other so, i thought, lets just put the columns after BC & we won't have any restrictions or 'there's already data there - do you want to overwrite it"

Comment: See my edit above - that will take the values from col BA and split them starting in col B*C*

Comment: Thank you guys soooooo much! i really appreciate your time, contributions and knowledge!!! Thank you a thousand times over!